# PdfSharp Image in Cell overlapping on other rows

Tags: c#, pdfsharp

I started using PDFSharp the day before yesterday and I used the following code to add an Image to a cell:

```
   Section section = this.document.AddSection();

   Table table1 = section.Headers.Primary.AddTable();

   Column column = table1.AddColumn("8.5cm");
   column.Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Right;

   column = table1.AddColumn("8.5cm");
   column.Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Right;

   Row row = table1.AddRow();       
   Image image = row.Cells[0].Elements.AddImage(@"C:\testdump\logo.jpg");
   image.LockAspectRatio = true;
   image.RelativeVertical = RelativeVertical.Line;
   image.RelativeHorizontal = RelativeHorizontal.Margin;
   image.Top = ShapePosition.Top;
   image.Left = ShapePosition.Left;
   image.WrapFormat.Style = WrapStyle.None;
```

I added another table after this one:

```
Table table2 = section.AddTable();
```

The image in the cell overlaps onto table2. Anyone know why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like adding a "blank" row to the second table solved the issue. Not sure how that solves the overlapping.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK the line

```
image.WrapFormat.Style = WrapStyle.None;
```

creates a free-floating image. The image gets its position from the cell, but has no effect on the layout of the table.

Use WrapStyle.None if you want to overlap the image with text or other elements.